# Facebook - serverfbml form action must be within the application's connect url

Tags: facebook

I am not sure, I am using a pretty standard piece of code for facebook. It sends requests for people regarding my application. All of a sudden I am receiving this error:

> serverfbml form action must be within
>   the application's connect url

Have you been having problems with using either one of these:

- fb:serverFbml
- fb:request-form
- fb:req-choice
- fb:multi-friend-selector

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same issue.. i used the canvas url in the summary page and it worked. You can try it out aswell

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you managed to find a solution yet, but I will tell you what my solution is. The action attribute of your forms should NOT be relative URLs, that is you should give the full URL of the website where the application is hosted:

`fb:editor action="http://www.mydomain.com/myapp/index.php?params=1" labelwidth="100"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the canvas URL under Facebook Integration section in your application's edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

If your canvas URL looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/myfacebookapp/
```

then, in server fbml form action, the URL MUST be in the same directory of your canvas, like this:

(using the example of

```
<fb:request-form action="http://www.example.com/myfacebookapp/somepage.html"
```

Also, if the whole contains blank spaces i.e.

```
http://www.example.com/myfacebookapp new/
```

consider eliminate that blanks, or use %20 instead of the blank when you specify the URL canvas on Facebook and when you use that URL in form

```
<fb:request-form action="http://www.example.com/myfacebookapp%20new/somepage.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it finally.
Dont get messed up with all type of setting.
Simply go to your facebook app
click edit app button
now copy Canvas URL
and paste it under

`<fb:request-form action="CANVAS URL HERE"
            method="POST">`

Well, it worked for me.!

Thanks to "tsegaye"

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution. If you do this, when user clicks "skip" on the dialog, he would be send to http://www.mydomain.com/myapp/index.php?params=1" instead of your application.
The solution is:
action="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/" -> this "/" at the end would help.
It could be also any other action inside your app for example:
action="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/sendRequest"

Answer (score 0):

This solution works if you use friend selectors outside the scope of sending requests. For eg. Selecting friends to collaborate with in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but this is what helped me. I have a iframe based application and i tried to use the facebook iframe based friend invite code. In my action, i put the app.facebook.com/myapp/ url which whould be give me this fbml error

```
serverfbml form action must be within the application's connect url
```

Also when i pressed "skip" it would take me to a 404 error. The solution was to use the canvas url under facebook integration, as suggested by @tsegaye